# FreshMvvm: Command.CanExecute called only once. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: freshmvvm

When using FreshMvvm for making Xamarin Forms apps, I *always* face the problem that the `CanExecute` method of a `Command` is called only once, and never again. As a result, if I disallow the `Command`'s execution initially, I cannot allow it later, and vice-versa. There must be something I am doing wrong.

I have made a small test app to demonstrate my code. **I would be grateful if you could take a look and point out my mistake.**

The app is very simple; just a single screen with a `Button` and a `Switch`.

- Tapping on the Button should display an alert.
- The Switch should toggle whether the Button is enabled.
- The Switch is bound to a `bool` property.
- The Button is bound to a `Command`.
- The `CanExecute` method of the Command returns the value of the bool property controlled by the Switch.
- The `Execute` method of the Command displays an Alert.
- In the PageModel's `init` method, I set the bool property to `false`.

**My MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FreshCommandTrial01"
             x:Class="FreshCommandTrial01.Pages.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout>
            <Button
                Text="Show Alert"
                Command="{Binding ShowAlertCommand}" />
            <Switch
                IsToggled="{Binding IsAlertAllowed}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**My MainPageModel.cs**

```
using FreshMvvm;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace FreshCommandTrial01.ViewModels
{
    public class MainPageModel : FreshBasePageModel
    {
        public override void Init(object initData)
        {
            IsAlertAllowed = false;
        }

        private bool _isAlertAllowed;
        public bool IsAlertAllowed
        {
            get { return _isAlertAllowed; }
            set
            {
                _isAlertAllowed = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsAlertAllowed");
                ShowAlertCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
            }
        }

        public Command ShowAlertCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(
                  () => ShowAlertCommand_Execute(),
                  () => ShowAlertCommand_CanExecute()
                  );
            }
        }

        private bool ShowAlertCommand_CanExecute()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("CanExecute called: IsAlertAllowed = " + IsAlertAllowed);
            return IsAlertAllowed;
        }

        private async void ShowAlertCommand_Execute()
        {
            await CoreMethods.DisplayAlert("Alert", "This is an alert", "OK");
        }
    }
}
```

***Expected Behavior***

- When the app is launched, the Switch is in the Off position, and the Button is disabled.
- When I toggle the Switch to the On position, the Command's `CanExecute` method is called again, and the Button becomes enabled.

***Oberserved Behavior***

- [**This is OK**] When the app is launched, the Switch is in the Off position, and the Button is disabled.
- [**This is not OK**] When I toggle the Switch to the On position, the CanExecute is not called, and the Button remains disabled.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of having Switch & calling `ChangeCanExecute`, just use a `bool` property, and bind `IsEnabled` of a button in XAML to this property + raise PropertyChanged on the `bool` property where you executed `ChangeCanExecute`.
I had the same issue and this was the only way it reliably worked.

Comment: @Eric: Thank you. Yes, using a bool works for me too. However, I would have preferred the "canonical" way of working.